# Показ соответствующих меню страниц

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Допустим, есть динамическое меню, выводимое через запрос из БД. Как генерировать выбор элемента? Т.е. мы нажали на какой-либо элемент и чтоб соответственно выбранному отображалась страница? У нас есть один шаблон для всех страниц. И чтоб этот шаблон (определенный его участок) заполнялся содержимым? Как я понял, мы при нажатии на элемент меню выполняем запрос к БД, где ид страницы относится к ид меню. Вот и как это сделать? Может, у кого есть примерные фрагменты кода? А то я что-то ковыряюсь и ничего не получается.

Меню - JS + CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос конечно мощный, прямо на разработку целой CMS :)
Но давайте попробуем изобразить что-нибудь.
Имеем один шаблон на все-про-все, готовое сгенерированное меню и таблицу в БД, в которой лежат наши странички.
Еще имеем страницу index.php (шаблон), в которой все и будет происходить, ну и 
меню пусть будет у нас вида:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="?id=1">Ссылка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="?id=2">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="?id=3">Ссылка 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Вот собственно и код этой страницы (index.php):

```
<?
// определяем значения по-умолчанию, которые будут выводится на странице index.php без ?id=ЧИСЛО
$pageTitle  = "Заголовок начальной страницы";
$pageContent    = "Текст начальной страницы";

// определяем, на какую ссылку кликнули и какую страницу с каким id будем вытаскивать из БД
if ( isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) ) {

// например, была нажата ссылка /index.php?id=2
// обращаемся к БД к таблице со страницами и вытаскиваем запись, id которой = 2
$sql = "SELECT title, content FROM pages WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
$pageTitle = $r["title"]; // это будет заголовок браузера
$pageContent = $r["content"]; // это будет контент страницы
}

}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title><?=$pageTitle;?></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800">
    <tr>
        <td width="300">
Меню
<br />
<ul>
    <li><a href="?id=1">Ссылка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="?id=2">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="?id=3">Ссылка 3</a></li>
</ul>
    </td>
        <td width="500">
Контент
<br />
<?=$pageContent;?>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Сейчас найдутся кодеры, которые скажут, что использовать mysql_query теперь не корректно, но для самой простецкой CMS пойдет и для данного примера более чем :)

Кстати, пример этой простецкой цмс можно посмотреть [здесь](http://tex-spassk.ru/tmp/test.php).

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
а почему использование mysql_query некорректно?

Comment: полагаю что это связано с тем что скоро библиотеку mysql уберут из php и вместо них надо будет использовать PDO или Mysqli